# How can I change the color of inner HTML var value text with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to color all the words that I choose in my input from my table rows. 
the rows table contains a string of paragraphs.

the issue of this code he just color a 1 word not all the words for the paragraphs also he adds the word that I want to color it in the front of the paragraph
for exp if I have two paragraphs he will color one word of from each paragraph and he will concatenate the word that I chose to color it in the begin of the second paragraph

my javascript code:

```
var word ='pregnant'; 
var a = row["Abstract"].substring(0, row["Abstract"].indexOf(word));
var b = row["Abstract"].substring(row["Abstract"].indexOf(word) + word.length);
```

HTML:

```
'<span style="color: black;">'+ a +'</span>' + '<span style="color: red;">'+ word +'</span>' + b
```

Comment: Please add your code to stackoverflow snippet....!

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the code as it is now splits your string in 2. The first string `a` spans from the beginning to the start of the first occurrence of the word and the second string `b` starts at the end of the word and spans to the end of the original string.

In essence, your code only considers the first occurrence of the word.

You could use regex to fix that, here is an example:

```js
var org = "Lorem replace ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore replace et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi replace ut aliquip ex ea replace commodo consequat";
var word = "replace";

var result = org.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"), `<span style="color: red;">${word}</span>`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! it works. I just change your result with my regular expression: var result = org.replace(new RegExp(word, "g"),'<span style="color: red;">'+word+'</span>'); bescause BIRT eclispe dont recognize the ${} .

Comment: @MokiNex That is call a *template literal* and it is not supported in all browsers, if you're using this in a web app, you're better off using the old string concatenation construct. I'm glad I could help and good luck.

Comment: Could you help me how to use regExp for multiple Input as string for example (replace|dolor)

Comment: @MokiNex you could do something like this: `org.replace(new RegExp("("+word1 + ")|(" + word2 + ")", "g"), function(m){
    return '<span style="color: '+(m === word1 ? "red" : "green")+'">' + m + '<span>';
});`. Here, the `m` parameter will be the matched group (`word1` or `word2`). Here is the documentation for [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: there is a possibility to do it with N words? because don't know exactly my input words it can be 2, 3, 5, n-words.. thanks you for your consideration

Comment: @MokiNex Yes, sure, that is possible. Try to understand what my previous example is doing and you will figure out how to modify it to make it work for multiple words.

Comment: var word1 =  'reference';
var word2= 'hormone'; 
var orgAbstruct = row["Abstract"];
var abstrutResult =orgAbstruct.replace(new RegExp("("+word1 + ")|(" + word2 + ")", "g"), function(m){ return '<span style="color: '+(m === word1 ? "red" : "green")+'">' + m + '<span>'; });

<html><B>Abstract :</B></html> +" "+abstrutResult;                                 I add this script to my Dynamic Text I don't know how it just color the first word in green and then when the function finds the second word it will color all the paragraph in red NOT just the words that I want

Comment: @MokiNex Create a variable `var color = "green"` before the `replace` call and then, inside `replace`'s callback function, use it to set the `span`'s color and change it to `"red"` after you find the first occurrence of the first word.

Comment: @MokiNex I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.
Can you show me the original string and the result you're looking for ?

Comment: i have some problem with this script  I have string array of word and I want to use their value as an input to color my paragraph could you help for that this is the LINK :https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/wncafj5f/38/

Comment: @MokiNex Use: `words.forEach....` instead of `words.split(" ").forEach....` https://jsfiddle.net/6vtco6fg/

Comment: but sometimes I have two words inside the array for example "Title":["reference serve " ,"testing"]  that why I put the split Methode

Comment: @MokiNex In that case, use `wordsArray.forEach(function (words) { words.split(" ").forEach(.....)` https://jsfiddle.net/6vtco6fg/2/

Comment: Thanks!! solve it but In my BIRT javascript he doesn't recognize this symbol  "=>" (arrow function) so I just replace the "=>" with function https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/6vtco6fg/5/  !Thank you!! now my last step if i have a string array of abstract row like this example https://jsfiddle.net/MokiNex/6vtco6fg/7/ need another loop !?

Comment: @MokiNex Not really, you'll end up repeating the original string multiple times. Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/6vtco6fg/29/ I've used another approach. I've merged all the words to create only one regex and use that regex to process all the element of the `Abstract` array. Try to understand what that code is doing and see how you can modify it to do what you want. If by now you didn't get how to do this, I'm afraid there is nothing more I can do for you.